# Querying Realm nested object slow

Tags: android, realm

I have a nested data model in Realm like the following filled with large amounts of data:

```
@RealmClass
public class RealmTopLevelObject extends RealmObject {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private RealmList<Level2Object> level2;
}

@RealmClass
public class Level2Object extends RealmObject {
    private String name;
    private RealmList<Level3Object> level3;
}
```

When I only need the `RealmTopLevelObject.name` I query the model like this:

```
mRealm
    .where(RealmTopLevelObject.class)
    .equalTo("id", queryId)
    .findFirst()
    .getName();
```

However, the query is very slow. I assume Realm loads the full nested object (including all nested `RealmList` objects).

What would be a way to solve this issue?

Comment: `I assume Realm loads the full nested object (including all nested RealmList objects).` wrong! I think it'd be better if we saw some additional context. `findFirst` by id shouldn't be slow, although you are missing your `@PrimaryKey`

Comment: You are right, I measured it and `findFirst` is very fast. My problem was that I have added an abstraction layer to map the `RealmObject`s to my model classes. Therefore, i actually access the `name` with `findfirst().toModelObject().getName()` where `toModelObject()` creates a new object of my model and inserts the complete nested object. Any ideas how to avoid that?

Comment: two solutions: 1.) don't map out the entire Realm database on the UI thread 2.) don't map out the Realm database

Comment: Realm itself does NOT load the full nested object unless accessed (it's lazy-loaded and stuff after all), but you do.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Unfortunately I need to use another model so I will go with solution 1 and map the objects only selectively.